# using htaccess in subfolders to redirects

Tags: apache, .htaccess, redirect, mod-rewrite

i'm running a site with 2 subfolders (different sites in each i.e. I have 3 different sites in one host) so my question is that,

1. can I use .htaccess file in the root of subfolders? will it work? or I have to do all from my main site root and .htaccess?
2. would you please suggest a common code for my sobfolders to redirect to www versions with .ir prefix and remove index.php?

i want this:

```
mysite.ir/news [or] mysite.com/news [or]
```

to

```
www.mysite.ir/news
```

and also to remove index.php:

```
mysite.ir/news/index.php?/title [or] mysite.com/news/index.php?/title
```

to

```
www.mysite.ir/news/title
```

Thank you guys, any would be much appreciated

Answer (score 0):

In the root folder of **mysite.com**. Create a `.htaccess` file with the below rules

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.mysite.ir/$1 [R=301,L]
```

In the root folder of **mysite.ir**. Create a `.htaccess` file with the below rules

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.mysite.ir/$1 [R=301,L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.+)/(.+)/$ /$1/index.php?/$2 [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.+)/(.+)$ /$1/index.php?/$2 [L]
```

Comment: thanks for the answer
mysite.com is just an alias domain for my main site (mysite.ir)
however, "forum" and "news" are two subfolders containing different site in each

Comment: So what is your problem?

Comment: 1. does the .htaccess file in the subfolder will work for the site in that subfolder?
2. i want to redirect "mysite.com/news/" to "mysite.ir/news/" and also remove index.php from address bar

Comment: Your first question is yes. For your second question. Put the second htaccess file mentioned above in that sub folder.